# Mysql Date between query not working

Tags: mysql, between

I'm trying the following and not working - producing zero results.

Quite tired after a 20hr + programming marathon but can't spot the mistake.

```
select count(*) from app where lastUpdate Between 2013-11-10 AND 2013-11-21
```

Comment: Query structure seems to be OK. But don't you get error message because dates are not quoted?

Comment: shouldn't the date be quoted?

Comment: Apparently this happens: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20133449/1688441

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dates are not quoted then they would perform calculations which would make the query actually be:

```
select count(*) from app where lastUpdate Between 1992 AND 1981
```

Answer (score 2):

No schema, but try:

```
select count(*) from app where lastUpdate Between '2013-11-10' AND '2013-11-21'
```